# Error 0x800706BA when creating user in a PDC. Has anyone seeen it before?

Tags: .net, active-directory

I'm attempting to create a new user using the following code snippet.

```
using (var ad = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
                        "<domain>", 
                        "<ad user>", 
                        "<ad pass>"))
{
    using (var aduser = new UserPrincipal(ad, "dummy", "password", false))
    {
        aduser.Save();
    }
}
```

However I get the message `RPC Unavailable` with the `0x800706BA` error code.

Has anyone seen it before?

And, more importat, solved it!

Comment: Are you running the code on a domain controller?  If you are running the code on a domain controller, can you create the User using ADUC but not using C# code?

Comment: I'm running the code **against** a PDC, but from a machine outside it's domain. However the user and passowrd used to connect is of an administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the AccountManagement interfaces provided by .NET 3.5 didn't work for my issue, falling back to the faithful LDAP worked. So I'm posting here to posterity.

```
/*
 * First we need to create the user...
 */
using (var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<IP/name>", 
                                         "<admin>", 
                                         "<admin pass>", 
                                          AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind))
{
  using (var newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=dummy", "user"))
  {
      newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = "dummy";
      newUser.CommitChanges();
  }
}

/*
 * Then set its password!
 *
 * If the password is set in the same 
 * transaction as the creation an error occurr.
 */
using (var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<IP/name>/CN=dummy,DC=corp", 
                                     "<admin>", 
                                     "<admin pass>"))
{
  user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "password" });
  user.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a general domain setup issue.  I bet you also couldn't use Active Directory User and Computer MMC snapin to create a new user from your machine.  I suggest you download [Windows 2003 Admin tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en) or [Windows 2008 Remote Server Administration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en) and try to do it manually from your machine first.

Once you prove this is a general domain setup issue, I think you can try to post your question on ServerFault.com.  You will get faster and better answer there.

In many AD operations such as password reset, the operation is done via MS-RPC but not LDAP.  So, I am not surprised to see `RPC server unavailable` error message when creating a new AD user.

There are many reasons causing the `RPC server unavailable`, you can check this [MSDN articile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727057.aspx) and see if you have any luck.

If you didn't setup Active Directory before, here are some basic information you need to know.

1) You need to make sure you are using correct DNS server.  Active Directory stores a lot of useful information on DNS.  It's not just your domain name and PDC name.  It has some service records.  If the target PDC is just a test domain that you setup, many programmer makes a mistake to just modify the local host file to resolve the PDC to an IP address.  This won't work and will cause some trouble down the road.

2) You need to make sure the clock on your development machine is in-sync with your PDC.  Kerberos authentication is time sensitive.  Active Directory is using Kerberos authentication.  This normally won't be a problem but some programmers like to use VM.  I saw there are some time lagging issues if you have many VM running on the same host.

3) Make sure your RPC service on the PDC is really running and not blocked by firewall.  If you are accessing a production domain, the network admin may block the access to port 135 for securirty reasons.

These are the best advice I can give.  Hope this helps.  If none of the above helps, I think you have to troubleshoot it by looking at the network packets.  Capture the network trace using wireshark.  Make sure you modify your code to don't use encryption by specifying `ContextOptions.SimpleBind` when constructing your `PrincipalContext`

> The worst thing is that while the
>   above code doesn't work, doing the
>   same thing via LDAP queries works like
>   a charm

`System.DirectoryService.AccountManagement` namepsace is using `DirectoryEntry` internally.  `DirectoryEntry` is using [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170%28VS.85%29.aspx) internally.  ADSI has a complicated logic to set the user's password.  There are three ways to set a user's password in Active Directory, with the following order

1. LDAP password update over an SSL channel
2. Kerberos set password using Kerberos protocol
3. MS-RPC call using port 135

ADSI won't use LDAP password update unless SSL is configured.  Unfortunately, the SSL is not configured properly out of the box.  You need to do extra configuration to make it working.  It's not configured because Windows itself doesn't really need to use SSL at all.  It has Kerberos in place working very well.  So, in your case, I bet option 1 will not be used.

Option 2 won't work either because you didn't point to the correct DNS.  You are using your own local host file.

Now, coming to option 3, the call can be successful only if your current thread security context is allowed.  From your description, it sounds like your workstation is not joined to that target domain at all.  So, I don't expect you have the Kerberos token.  Normally, it should fall back to use NTLM.  If you have a domain user with the same username and password as your user account used in your workstation, it should work.  You also need to make sure that domain user account has appropriate right.  Anyway, it's out of my knowlege.

The fact is that you are getting `RPC server unavailable`.  You must be failing all three options.

Yes, you made it working by using LDAP query.  Perhaps, it works just because you are using the simple LDAP with no SSL at all.  That means your password is in plain text format on the wire.

My suggestion is to fix your workstation to use the DNS on that domain controller.  Everything should just work.

**UPDATED**

I didn't read your posted solution before replying you.  If you got `DirectoryEntry` approach working, I don't understand why `AccountManagement` approach doesn't work.  To understand the difference, we may need to disassemble it.

Comment: The worst thing is that while the above code doesn't work, doing the same thing via LDAP queries works like a charm. True, due the some weird internal coding of the Active Directory I need to first commit the creation of the user, THEN set its passowrd. 

And yes, I'm guilty of the item #1 you mentioned, however the other two items was not a problem.

Comment: @Paulo My reply is too long.  I put it in my answer