# Setting Active Directory User Password Error (RPC-Server is unavailable)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

I'm creating an ASP.NET Web Application which should set a password on an event. 
Now I always get the error "RPC-Server is unavailable. (Exception HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "FOOBAR.LOC", @"FOOBAR\Administrator", "password");

UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "myuser");
principal.SetPassword("newpassword");
```

I searched the whole internet for a solution but couldn't find any.

Cheers

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons.  One common reason is you have firewall blocking your domain controller port 135 or other related ports.  Check with your network administrator.

Comment: @Kingfleur Did you get the solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DirectoryEntry object to set the password :

```
using (var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<IP/name>/CN=dummy,DC=corp", 
                                     "<admin>", 
                                     "<admin pass>"))
{
  user.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "password" });
  user.CommitChanges();
}
```

As explained in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4895603/971

Answer (score -1):

The first result:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935677

Comment: I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2010 on Windows 7. The domain controller is a Windows Server 2008 R2.